# Identify a vector within a list with at least n ocurrences of given value in R

Tags: r, list, vector, run-length-encoding

I would like to write a function which would allow to filter the input data.
My input data is a list object containing named numeric vectors (minimal reproducible example below - dummy list).

```
vec1 <- c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 4), rep(0,5), rep(-1,5))
vec2 <- c(rep(-1, 7), rep(0,99), rep(1, 6))
vec3 <- c(rep(1,2), rep(-1,2), rep(0,10), rep(-1,4), rep(0,8))
vec4 <- rep(0, 100)

dummy_list <- list(vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4)
names(dummy_list) <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
```

I want my function to test whether in this vector any non-zero value occurs at least 5 times in a row.

My desired output should be a list containing only first two vectors of the initial dummy_list.

Below is one of my multiple attempts - I would like it to be as much similar to this as possible (except that the solution should work).

```
dummy_list <- Filter(function(x) which(rle(x$values !=0) x$lengths>5, dummy_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we check whether any of the the rle `length` is greater or equal to 5.

```
Filter(function(x)any(with(rle(x), lengths[values!=0]>=5)), dummy_list)

$first
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

$second
  [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [32]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [63]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [94]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the "\" in the front - does this replace a certain function call?

Comment: @ramen its just the short form of rewritting function of x. I have replaced it with the word function. Now it should work. Note that the notation `\(x)` is used in R version >4.1